# How to format math expression string to the JS string

Tags: javascript, java, string, math, eval

I have, for example, string `a^2 + 2ab + b^2`, but I need to format it to the eval-able string `Math.pow(a, 2) + 2*a*b + Math.pow(b, 2)` JS string.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You'd have to parse your starting grammar and then traverse the syntax tree to output the desired form.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to basically take input like `a^2` and then transform it to `Math.pow(a, 2)` and so on, is that correct?

Comment: So I have to iterate char-by-char and then transform the source string into the evalable one?

@vlaz yes

Comment: Any code what you done?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [math.js](http://mathjs.org/index.html)?

Example:

```
var node = math.parse('x^a', scope);
var code = node.compile();
var scope = {
    x: 3,
    a: 2
};
code.eval(scope); // 9
```

Comment: ugh, I could if I were using JS, but I'm using Java (sorry I forgot about java tag)

oh well, I'm evaling it anyways.

Comment: @KeterDev what the hell? Really? You FORGOT about that?

Comment: im new to stackoverflow